# Turning factor vectors into columns with binary variables in R

Tags: r

A similar question may have been asked before, but I can't find the exact scenario. I have some data, say,

```
> t <- data.frame(project=c("A","A","B","C","C"),lang=factor(c("X","Y","X","Y","Z")))
> t
  project lang
1       A    X
2       A    Y
3       B    X
4       C    Y
5       C    Z
```

And I would like to turn it into the following

```
  project X Y Z
1       A 1 1 0
2       B 1 0 0
3       C 0 1 1
```

That is, I would like to turn each factor level in `lang` into a column which has value `1` if there is a row `i` in `t` where `lang[i]` has that level, and `0` otherwise. I can hack it together with some for loops and whatnot, but is there an easier way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is always `table`:

```
> table(t)
       lang
project X Y Z
      A 1 1 0
      B 1 0 0
      C 0 1 1
```

---

Depending on the behavior you want where there are duplicates (so tabulation would yield a number greater than one) you may need to do an additional step:

```
## New sample data with a duplicated "A, X" combination
t <- data.frame(project=c("A","A","A", "B","C","C"),
                lang=factor(c("X","Y","X", "X","Y","Z")))

out <- table(t)
out
#        lang
# project X Y Z
#       A 2 1 0
#       B 1 0 0
#       C 0 1 1
out[out >= 1] <- 1
out
#        lang
# project X Y Z
#       A 1 1 0
#       B 1 0 0
#       C 0 1 1
```